# What am I missing with about import?

Tags: python, import

First time asking here and I'm new to Python. I'm also starting lose my cool with the `import` system. I have a folder called "moduuliharkka", which has main.py and country_data.py inside of it. country_data only contains 3 dictionaries used for a script (main.py should fetch the data from there). My problem is, main.py doesn't want to import country_data for some unknown reason.

This is country_data.py:

```
countrycodes = ["fi","se","no"]
codemap = {
"fi":'finland', "se":'sweden', "no":'norway'
}
countries = {
'finland':{'head honcho':('Juha Sipila','54 years old'),'population':5.349},
'sweden':{'head honcho':('Stefan Lofven','58 years old'),'population':9.593},
'norway':{'head honcho':('Erna Solberg','54 years old'),'population':5.084}
}
```

and this is main.py:

```
import country_data

for code in countrycodes:
    print (codemap[code], ':\n\t','Head honcho:', countries[codemap[code]]['head honcho'],'\n\t','Population:', countries[codemap[code]]['population'],'million')
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Kouluhommelit\Script-programming\moduuliharkka\main.py", line 3, in <module>
for code in countrycodes:
NameError: name 'countrycodes' is not defined
```

I've been struggling on this for nearly 2 hours now. The program works when I put the contents of country_code above the script in main.py. Am I missing something really obvious? Does my problem have something to do with the folder structure, syntax or possibly something else?

Comment: After `import country_data`, `countrycodes` list is only accessible as `country_data.countrycodes`.

Comment: It is `country_data.countrycodes`, or you can (but this is really bad design), use `from country_data import *`.

Comment: You can remplace `import country_data` by `from .country_data import countrycodes, codemap, countries` or simply `from .country_data import * `

Comment: @ChihebNexus Not sure about the leading `.` there, that might work only for relative imports within packages?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes it'll work only with relative imports with package this why i think the best practice is to add an `__init__` file to every folder and use them like a packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `import country_data`, you can access the variables in that module like so:

```
country_data.countrycodes
country_data.codemap
country_data.countries
```

Your new `main.py` would be:

```
import country_data

for code in country_data.countrycodes:
    print(country_data.codemap[code], ':')
    print('\t', 'Head honcho:', country_data.countries[country_data.codemap[code]]['head honcho'])
    print('\t', 'Population:', country_data.countries[country_data.codemap[code]]['population'], 'million')
```

Comment: Ah, so I'd have to refactor the main script part by replacing the old values with country_data.*whatevervalue*s?

Update: working now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score -2):

you cannot cycle the variables or lists or dictionaries of another file like that, image country_data.py as a class and countrycodes, codemap, countries are the fields, you cannot cycle through them, you must call them using the dot operator for example country_data.countrycodes[2] gives you "no", but you cannot cycle through them, **files are not iterable objects**

Comment: Well, the code is working now as intended, even though it looks pretty ugly. I'm not iterating a file, I'm iterating an imported dictionary.

Comment: @JesseKämäräinen I'm very sorry I read `for code in countrycodes` as `for code in country_data`